# MVC Authorization asks for login everytime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, web-config, forms-authentication

I am using autorize attribute on controller

```
  [Authorize(Roles = "Investor")]
public class InvestorIncomeController : Controller
{
  // some stuff
```

When I register new account and try to use this controller everytime it asks for login again and after logging again it works.

In webconfig file

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />


<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

I want if user logs in one time he shouldn't need to login again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this attribute above your Register method.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{

}
```

Comment: Please check and let me know

Comment: I have registered user with Investor role, so I want it to access that method as soon as I register, when I log in again it allows me to use that method but not when I register it